# Is there a "stable" version to use of the npm packages ui5/cli & sap-ux-tooling?

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

To my knowledge, the latest non-alpha version of the @ui5/cli and @sap/ux-ui5-tooling (as of 2nd March 2022 - version [2.14.6](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui5/cli/v/2.14.6) and [1.5.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/ux-ui5-tooling/v/1.5.0) respectively) are the ones to use.

However, I wanted to confirm as my organisation has multiple ui5 projects and so having a standardised version of the @ui5/cli and @sap/ux-ui5-tooling dependencies could prevent issues around bugs in tooling.

If the advice is just to use the latest non-alpha version, then I just need to update the dependencies regularly.

Answer (score 0):

The versions you mentioned should be your choice to use in a productive environment.

The upcoming [UI5 tooling 3.0](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/506) is not.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I will follow that advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will achieve the same version in every app because of the lifecycle.

The packages are fast paced and when u have a stable app deployed you will not update it every month I think.

I would not invest time to find the perfect tooling version.